# How to change product price to custom text Magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, price, custom-attributes, product-prices

I am planning to change product price from
Category view and product page to “coming soon” I have a new product attribute which I have created and I can see that when I edit product page from admin area.
If I enable that attribute the price is meant to change from the amount to “coming soon”

This is my **Di.xml** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Product page -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="[vendor]\[module]\Plugin\Model\Product"/>
    </type>

    <!-- Price changed in category level -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="cataloghideprice_finalpricebox" type="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
    </type>

</config>
```

The category level works perfectly
I can see coming soon, but the issue I am having is product page isn’t changing

Please can someone direct me to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create `catalog_product_prices.xml` into your extension on following path :
   vendor\Extension\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml
2. Now copy the orginal file content `catalog_product_prices.xml` from following location :
   vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml
3. Now replace following line

   ```
   <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
   ```

   with this :

   ```
   <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
   ```
4. Now copy the template file from

   ```
   Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   Vendor_Extension::product/price/amount/default.phtml
   ```
5. Now apply your logic into this file :

   ```
   Vendor_Extension::product/price/amount/default.phtml
   ```

Comment: How is this overriding the category or product page. Product/price/amount/default.phtml would this change the price for both area

Comment: you need to create that file into given templates folder and it will use to show on the product page.

Comment: I am kinda confused, I haven’t tried it I thought I will double check. This current default.phtml would this change on both areas as in product page and category level or would I need to change somewhere else as well

Comment: You can re-write this and then check.

Comment: Hi @DhirenVasoya  sure I will give this a go today and let you know but thank you as well for the help. 

Comment: this is a good method but I am unable to check the attribute there I can add a custom text but wouldn’t let me to check product attribute.

Comment: Is there any example you could give me here @DhirenVasoya

Comment: @JackBrooks I give you all the code above, you need to just put your coe of logic into phtml file.

Comment: the phtml use $block which is coming cron Magento\framework but I couldn’t get my after plugin in which checks the price.

Comment: I don’t want to put object manger in phtml, I believe there is a way to get it working with object manager

Comment: @JackBrooks there are otherway as well, pass the your class as argument and use those one, so no need to use Object Manager.

Comment: If above answer help you, then upvote and mark as solution so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: the class argument, currently the default.phtml uses core Magento/framework class but this for pricing. I believe the pricing template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111125/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-jack-brooks).

Comment: I am unsure how to check the attribute is enabled for products and then change the price  I have used after plunging for this Magento catalog block product listproduct class

Comment: let have talk in chat group.